# How to trim spaces within timestamps using 'm/d/yy' format

Tags: python, datetime, trim

I have a Python script that generates .csv files from other data sources.

Currently, an error happens when the user manually adds a space to a date by accident. Instead of inputting the date as "1/13/17", a space may be added at the front (" 1/13/17") so that there's a space in front of the month.

I've included the relevant part of my Python script below:

```
def processDateStamp(sourceStamp):
    matchObj = re.match(r'^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s', sourceStamp)
    (month, day, year) = (matchObj.group(1), matchObj.group(2), matchObj.group(3))
    return "%s/%s/%s" % (month, day, year)
```

How do I trim the space issue in front of **month** and possibly on other components of the date (the day and year) as well for the future?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're dealing with dates, it might be more appropriate to use `datetime.strptime` than regex here. There are two advantages of this approach:

- It makes it slightly clearer to anyone reading that you're trying to parse dates.
- Your code will be more prone to throw exceptions when trying to parse data that doesn't represent dates, or represent dates in an incorrect format - *this is good because it helps you catch and address issues that might otherwise go unnoticed*.

Here's the code:

```
from datetime import datetime


def processDateStamp(sourceStamp):
    date = datetime.strptime(sourceStamp.replace(' ', ''), '%M/%d/%y')
    return '{}/{}/{}'.format(date.month, date.day, date.year)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(processDateStamp('1/13/17'))     # 1/13/17
    print(processDateStamp(' 1/13/17'))    # 1/13/17
    print(processDateStamp(' 1 /13 /17'))  # 1/13/17
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `parser` from [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. The main benefit you will get - it can recognize the datetime format for you (sometimes it may be useful):

```py
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

def processDateTimeStamp(sourceStamp):
    dt = parser.parse(sourceStamp)
    return dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y")

processDateTimeStamp(" 1 /13 / 17")  # returns 01/13/17
processDateTimeStamp(" jan / 13 / 17")
processDateTimeStamp(" 1 - 13 - 17")
processDateTimeStamp(" 1 .13 .17")
```

Answer (score 0):

Once again, a perfect opportunity to use `split`, `strip`, and `join`:

```
def remove_spaces(date_string):
    date_list = date_string.split('/')
    result = '/'.join(x.strip() for x in date_list)
    return result
```

**Examples**

```
In [7]: remove_spaces('1/13/17')
Out[7]: '1/13/17'

In [8]: remove_spaces(' 1/13/17')
Out[8]: '1/13/17'

In [9]: remove_spaces(' 1/ 13/17')
Out[9]: '1/13/17'
```